# Yii2 how to implementation Optimistic Locks

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, optimistic-locking

Yii2 how to implementation Optimistic Locks.
I'm trying to follow this [official doc.](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#optimistic-locks)

I thought I carefully follow the step.
but still error : 
[image]

Here my procedure.

1. Create a column in the DB "version defualt velue = '0'
   [image]

2.Model.php

```
use yii\behaviors\OptimisticLockBehavior;

class OptimisticTest extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'optimistictest';
    }


    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['version'], 'required'],
                [['created_by', 'updated_by','version'], 'integer'],
            ];
        }

  public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
               'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            [
               'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            ],
            [
                 'class' => OptimisticLockBehavior::className(), //'getLockAttribute' =>$this->version
           ],
        ];
    }

}
```

3. myController.php

   ```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
   {
     $model = $this->findModel($id);
     $tempDocs = $model->docs;
     $modelRunning = $this->findModelRunning($model->running_id);
     $model->scenario = 'update';
    try {
       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
           $modelRunning->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
           Model::validateMultiple([$model,$modelRunning]))
       {
         if($modelRunning->save())
           {
           $this->CreateDir($model->ref);
           $model->docs = $this->uploadMultipleFile($model,$tempDocs);
           $model->save();
           }
           return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
       } else {
           return $this->render('update', [
               'model' => $model,
               'modelRunning' => $modelRunning,
           ]);
       }
   } catch (StaleObjectException $e) {
       // logic to resolve the conflict
         Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger',Yii::t('app', 'Record can not be updated, there is a user associated with it'));
           return $this->redirect(['index']);
   }}
   ```

Error is From Model.php in public function behaviors()

in step 1. Override this method to return the name of this column. 
how to override this method.
what i'm missing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `optimisticLock()` method means, that you have to implement the method in your model so it can be used instead of default implementation.

Your model should look like this

```
class OptimisticTest extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    //... your other methods in model

    public function optimisticLock()
    {
        //this method should return the name of version attribute
        return 'version';
    }
}
```